# Installing Madlib in Cent OS

Tags: centos, centos7, madlib

I am new to CentOS (Linux in general) and have been having a very difficult time installing Postgresql and Madlib. I am fairly confident I have successfully installed Postgresql. I am having trouble with the using the wget command with the correct address for the rpm.

[Link to Madlib download page](http://madlib.incubator.apache.org/download.html)

I have tried

```
wget http://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/incubator/madlib/1.9-incubating/apache-madlib-
1.9-incubating-bin-Linux.rpm
```

but get the error

```
--2016-08-21 00:48:09--  http://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/incubator/madlib/1.9-incubating
/apache-madlib-1.9-incubating-bin-Linux.rpm Resolving dist.apache.org (dist.apache.org)... failed: 
Name or service not known. wget: unable to resolve host address ‘dist.apache.org’
```

I do not know what to do. Most of the documentation I can find is for older versions and it seemed that the site was hosted on a different web address from where it is now.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general system configuration/DNS tech support. Maybe try superuser.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem